# Gathering stats, like number of views for a web page

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I'm working on a web site (PHP/JS/MYSQL).
I want to track the number of views for specific pages. I understand that updating DB each time the user gets to a page is not a good option. Can someone recommend a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using one of the many analytics services such as Google Analytics?

Comment: It's perfectly ok to update the DB on each page view.

Comment: Both comment are true. My answer below explains why. Googe Analytics is ultimately the more superior choice - although updating the db is just fine. You may want to study on your MySQL, Postgresql, or what have you for a database in order to ensure secure updating as well as stability should you views be large - as well as repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said I would use Google Analytics. This is a much simpler in means of effort and time. Not only is this better in those ways, but it's been in development for a while. It may very well be something that could take years to replicate if your skill-set is even that intense. :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using Google Analytics.

Its unbelieveably easy.

Just go to http://www.google.com/analytics/ and create and account.
(if you dont have a gmail account then i would create one first)

Then follow the instructions etc and paste your code on each page.

Here is a sample of the code (you would of course use your own numbers after UA):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
```

They even provide this code ready to paste in.

That is enough to set you up for what you asked for and also opens you up to a massive range of other tracking options if you want to track more stuff.

Best of all, its free!